# Canvas.drawText() not working

Tags: android

I am trying to draw text on a live wallpaper that has a background image on it. I was hoping to draw color on the canvas with Transparent so that it didn't cover up the background Image but for some reason it is not drawing the text onto the canvas.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
paintText = new Paint(); 
paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paintText.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
paintText.setTextSize(20); 

canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(Points) + " Points", 50, 50, paintText);
```

Comment: Hmm, what about Color.WHITE instead of Color.TRANSPARENT?

Comment: Ok I tried Color.WHITE and changed the text color to Color.BLACK but all I get is a full white screen with no text.

Comment: @Gatekeeper   put this `canvas.restore();`  after `drawText()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you do not need the

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

before drawing the text. Have you tried it without?

Comment: Just tried without that and still nothing. Does it matter if I use             canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint); right before all of this? I've seen a few tutorials that state you need to draw a solid color on the canvas before adding text but then it would cover up my bitmap

Comment: your canvas is in an imageview right? can you call .invalidate() on your imageview after the drawtext method?

Comment: I'm within a Live Wallpaper so my canvas is a canvas I believe. canvas = new Canvas();

Comment: Ahh got it, the text was off the screen for some reason, but you are correct the canvas.drawColor() is not needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

update your code:

```
paintText = new Paint(); 
paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paintText.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
paintText.setTextSize(20); 
 canvas.save();  //
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(Points) + " Points", 50, 50, paintText);
 canvas.restore();  //
```